# Meaning of statement class a(b)

Tags: c++

I have one doubt in C++ progaramming.

what is the meaning of statement `class a(b)` in c++ and also how to implement this?
Can we declare a class like this?

Comment: You really need to read a book or introduction. A question like this, means you have not tried.

Comment: Statement `class a(b)` has no meaning, and therefore it can not be implemented.

Comment: That statment is illegal, would give you a compilation error and means nothing. I guess you are asking something else. Could you please be a bit more precise?

Comment: @Dialecticus, @Gorpik: Isn't that just declaring and calling the constructor and allocating the value on the stack? (sorry my C++ is uber-rusty)

Comment: You've doubt even before opening a c++ basic book?

Comment: @leppie: You would have to give the class instance a name: `class a c(b);`

Comment: @Charles Bailey: OK, I interpreted it as `class` would be substituted for the actual type name, but yeah, I agree with you :)

Comment: Just a note that this is python syntax for declare a class `a` that inherits from `b`.

Answer (score 3):

```
class a(b)
```

is illegal in C++ and would result in a compilation error.

I'm not sure what you are actually meaning to ask. Maybe revise your question to be more specific or include more code and context?

Comment: I think this should just be a comment, but +1 for writing the nicest comment.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else; it seems that you are a little bit confused. Let's see if this helps.

In C++ class a(b) is illegal. However, if you want class a to accept an argument b, you would create a constructor within the class as follows

```
#include <iostream>
class a
{
    /**
     * Constructors have no type and are setup like a normal function. (They _MUST_
     * have the same name as their class/struct)
     * Generally, the class/struct is located within a ".h" while the actual code
     * is in a corresponding ".cpp" or ".cxx" file. However, in this example
     * I simply combined the class and its code function definitions.
     */
    a(char* b)
    { 
        std::cout<< b << std::endl;
    }
    ~a(){} // Same thing with destructors
};
```

In this case, argument "b" is defined as a char*, so you would then initialize this class as follows

```
int main()
{
    char* bptr = "test_for_pointer"; // Our variable to pass
    char* b = "test_non_pointer";
    a *ptr = new a(bptr); // Pointer declaration
    a tclass(b); // <--- Is this what you were looking to do? 

    // At this point, because of the constructors, both string should have been printed.
    delete ptr; // Clean up the pointer
    ptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice in the example that when declaring variables to hold the class a data, we declare their type a "a" and initialize with "new a()" (if it's a pointer) or simply "a VAR_NAME(CONSTRUCTOR_PARAMETERS_LIKE_NORMAL_FUNCTION)"

I hope this helped! It's not easy starting out with C++ - you'll have to do a lot of reading, but you'll get it!

Good luck!
Dennis M.